# Solving an unconstrained optimization problem in R

Tags: r, math, optimization

I am working on an assignment where I need to find the extreme point of a function.

My maximization function is `(x*26.7-2*x^2)/2`. This equation is the objective function with the constrain plugged-in.

In order to find the extreme point, I must be calculating the first-order derivative, set this function equal to zero and solve this equation. I know how to solve such a problem by hand but I was wondering what is the appropriate way to implement it in R.

Here is a toy example:

```
# First order derivative
f=expression((x*26.7-2*x^2)/2)
derivative <- D(f, 'x')
```

Now I'm not sure how to set `derivative` to zero and get an estimate of the root of the function in code.

To solve this in SAS, we can do the following

```
proc optmodel;

   var x;

   max z=(x*26.7-2*x**2)/2;

   solve;


   print x;

   quit;
```

Comment: The command `polyroot(c(0, 26.7/2, -1))` gives the answer to your question, but I'm not sure that this is the function that you are looking for.

Comment: Try `nlm(function(x) -(x*26.7-2*x^2)/2, 0)$estimate` or `optim(0, function(x) -(x*26.7-2*x^2)/2)$par` and you will get `6.675`.